# Webmin + SSH Public Key

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, public-key

Is it possible to upload a UNIX user's public key to Webmin? I would think this would be on this screen, but I'm not finding it....

[image]

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it there. Upload the public key, move it to `~/.ssh`, and give it the right permissions.

Comment: I think it's a great question. To me it was also unclear. So the steps are: 1. add to authorized_keys in ~/.ssh ... thats it??? or do we also need to create a user and link the keys?